how to build vscode in web
when i try npm run compile-web in terminal, it doesn't work
[error message in my terminal]
 details: 'ts-loader-default_71e2b19936f66ae7',
  stack: 'Error: \x1B[90m[tsl] \x1B[39m\x1B[1m\x1B[31mERROR\x1B[39m\x1B[22m\x1B[1m\x1B[31m in \x1B[39m\x1B[22m\x1B[1m\x1B[36m/Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/tsServer/serverProcess.browser.ts(154,14)\x1B[39m\x1B[22m\n' +
    '\x1B[1m\x1B[31m      TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.\x1B[39m\x1B[22m\n' +
    '    at makeError (/Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/utils.js:93:19)\n' +
    '    at /Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/utils.js:63:27\n' +
    '    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at formatErrors (/Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/utils.js:46:14)\n' +
    '    at /Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/after-compile.js:153:66\n' +
    '    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at provideErrorsToWebpack (/Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/after-compile.js:150:31)\n' +
    '    at /Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/after-compile.js:36:9\n' +
    '    at /Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/instances.js:206:13\n' +
    '    at fn (/Users/yinshi/work/vscode-main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:491:10)'

i got a lot of ts error
did i miss something? i have already install the node_modules
in out folder, i did not find out-web or something

Where did you get that source code?  The current git repo looks OK.

This type of question is probably better addressed to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues
